# Assembly PIC16F84A 0-99 porta=tens portb=ones

Tags: assembly, pic

I'm trying to make a counter that counts from 00 to 99, pins 0-3 on PORTB count from 1 to 9, and when 9 is reached, PORTA is supposed to increment by 1, then go back to the portb subroutine and so on, i've recently started to learn assembly and my logic told me this should work, but it doesn't, why though? Here is my code:

```
list p=16f84A
include <p16f84A.inc>
__CONFIG _CP_OFF & _WDT_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _XT_OSC 

org 0

;SETTING PORTS

BSF 03h,5 ;Changing STATUS to bank 1
MOVLW B'00000' ; Set all pins on
MOVWF 85h      ; PortA to output
MOVLW B'00000000' ;Set all pins on
MOVWF 86h         ; PortB to output
BCF 03h,5         ;Changing STATUS to bank 0
MOVLW 00h   ;Starting portA pins
MOVWF 05h   ; on cero
MOVLW 00h   ;Starting portB pins
MOVWF 06h   ; on cero
MOVLW 09h   ; Saving 9 on W
MOVWF 0Ch   ; Loading that 9 into the general purpose register 0Ch
MOVLW 09h   ; Saving 9 on W
MOVWF 0Dh   ; Loading that 9 into the general purpose register 0Dh

;START OF CODE

START
    MOVLW 09h ; Loading general purpose register 
    MOVWF 0Ch ; 0Ch with 9
    MOVLW 00h ; Setting PORTB
    MOVWF 06h ; pins all to 0
    GOTO START1 ; 

START1
    INCF 06h ;Incrementing PORTB by 1
    DECFSZ 0Ch ; Decrementing general purpose 0Ch previously set to 9, by 1, skip next instruction if 0Ch=0
    GOTO START1
    GOTO START2

START2
    INCF 05h ; Increment PORTA by 1
    DECFSZ 0Dh ; Decrementing general purpose 0Dh previously set to 9 by 1, skip next instruction if 0Dh=0
    GOTO START ; Goes back to START
    GOTO STARTOFSTARTS ; Goes to the label that sets everything back to their original values

STARTOFSTARTS 
    MOVLW 00h ; 
    MOVWF 05h ;Places all pins of PORTA on 0V
    MOVLW 00h ;
    MOVWF 06h ;Places all pins of PORTB on 0V
    MOVLW 09h ; 
    MOVWF 0Ch ;Loads general purpose 0Ch with 9
    MOVLW 09h ;
    MOVWF 0Dh ;Loads general purpose 0Dh with 9
    GOTO  START  goes back to start from 0 because 99 was already reached
    END
```

[image]

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: It shows random numbers and both portb and porta change at the same time

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe you are not supposed to read from the ports (and the INCF implicitly does read-modify-write). What happens if you just copy the registers `0C`/`0D` to the ports? That should of course count down, but could be a quick test.

Comment: There's no delay in your code and a PIC16F84A can be clocked up to 20MHz. Are you sure the numbers aren't changing so fast that they appear to be changing randomly?

Comment: I'm having issues with adding delays, they don't show up on the ISIS Proteus, i don't know if it's because of me or because of the simulator